Connecting an external monitor to an ASUS Vivobook using USB 3.2 Gen 1 Type-C® port using the Baseus portal joy 13-port hub BS-OH119
I need to be able to connect two external monitors to my laptop: ASUS VIVOBook X415EA_F14400EZ.
This laptop only has one HDMI Port but it does have one USB 3.2 Gen 1 Type-C® port. Does anyone know the exact adapter that will work to run a monitor?
I bought the Baseus Portal Joy 13-port hub BS-OH119 so I could use the HDMI and the ethernet connection but nothing works.

Does your laptop's USB C port support DisplayPort or Thunderbolt? Does the dock require one of these?

The answer to the above is no, so what you want can't be done.

Just because you have a USB C port does not mean your laptop supports display output on it. The specifications for your laptop need to specifically say that it supports display output on that port. For example a different laptop states "1x USB 3.2 Gen 2 Type-C support display / power delivery" while yours does not

Thank you for answering.  Based on music2myear and ChanganAuto above my laptop is limited to only one external monitor because the USB-c does not support a display.  And my laptop only has one HDMI port.

Your dock is a ThunderBolt dock. In order to do more than be an expensive USB hub it requires your computer to have a ThunderBolt controller inside it.
Bad news: Your computer doesn't have a ThunderBolt controller.
